# Why use little here in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Other experts also have little doubt that China was behind this
>   attack.

This is quoted from: http://motherboard.vice.com/read/did-china-just-launch-a-cyber-attack-on-github

When I was learning English I was told `little` means very very less while `a little` means some. According to the context it seems the experts were quite sure it's an attack from the China Government, then why not use `a little doubt` here. What kind of meaning is the author trying to convey?

Comment: What you were told is correct and it applies to your example sentence. Try to think of *little* as almost none or virtually none: *Other experts also have almost no doubt that China was behind this attack.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "a little doubt" would focus on the doubt, whereas "little doubt" focuses on the high level of certainty.

So, the "little doubt" version means **"Other experts are pretty much certain...",**

but the "a little doubt" version would mean: **"Other experts are not absolutely sure..."**

Comment: oh, it seems I just asked a very stupid question! thanks! when two negative words combined together I sometimes make such kind of mistakes.

Comment: Hmm. I think your question was actually a very good one. The difference in meaning between "little" and "a little" is rather subtle and it deserves being asked about. Shrug. :-)